# Hanging section - Memoir

Tags: formatting, memoir

I would like to obtain something like this:

[image]

So far I have this:

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Layout
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}  
\settypeblocksize{562pt}{330pt}{*}
\setlrmargins{200pt}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{114pt}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{12pt}{24pt}
\setheaderspaces{*}{24pt}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Remove chapter number
\renewcommand*\printchapternum{} 

% From p.96 - Memoir Manual 
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
\parbox[t][0pt]{10em}{\upshape\sffamily\raggedright\mbox{} #1}}
\newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{%
{\llap{\marginbox{#1}\kern3em}}}
\setsecindent{0em}
\setaftersecskip{0em}
\setsecheadstyle{\marginhead}
\setaftersecskip{0em}
\setsechook{\setsecnumformat{\csname the##1\endcsname\ }}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduccion}

\section{Objeto}
\lipsum[4]

\section{Comitente}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:**
The options on memoir manual p.96 are for paragraphs. I changed them to sections.
The line after the section number is not necessary, but I would like to get the section number, a line break and the section title like in the first image.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). The best approach would be to start with the `memoir` documentation and start to code what you can. When you get stuck, prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and post it here. People will be happy to help you with any specific problems you encounter.

Comment: I updated my answer providing an option with the horizontal rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Layout
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}  
\settypeblocksize{562pt}{330pt}{*}
\setlrmargins{200pt}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{114pt}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{12pt}{24pt}
\setheaderspaces{*}{24pt}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Remove chapter number
\renewcommand*\printchapternum{} 

% From p.96 - Memoir Manual 
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
  \parbox[t][0pt]{10em}{%
  \upshape\sffamily\raggedright\mbox{}#1}%
}
\newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{%
  \smash{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\llap{\marginbox{#1}\kern3em}}}%
}
\setsecindent{0em}
\setsecheadstyle{\marginhead}
\setbeforesecskip{1em}
\setaftersecskip{0em}
\setsechook{%
  \setsecnumformat{\csname   the##1\endcsname\enspace\par\nobreak}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduccion}

\section{Objeto}
\lipsum[4]

\section{Comitente}
\lipsum[4]

\section{A test section with a longer title}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with the rules:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

% Layout
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}  
\settypeblocksize{562pt}{330pt}{*}
\setlrmargins{200pt}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{114pt}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{12pt}{24pt}
\setheaderspaces{*}{24pt}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Remove chapter number
\renewcommand*\printchapternum{} 

% From p.96 - Memoir Manual 
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
  \parbox[t][0pt]{10em}{%
  \upshape\sffamily\raggedright\mbox{}#1}%
}
\newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{%
  \smash{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\llap{\marginbox{#1}\kern3em}}}%
}

\newcounter{tmp}

\setsecindent{0em}
\setbeforesecskip{1em}
\setaftersecskip{0em}
\setsechook{\stepcounter{tmp}%
  \setsecnumformat{\csname  the##1\endcsname\enspace\tikzmark{\thetmp}\par\nobreak%
 }\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:\thetmp) -- ([yshift=1ex]current page text area.east|-{pic cs:\thetmp});
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\setsecheadstyle{\marginhead}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduccion}

\section{Objeto}
\lipsum[4]

\section{Comitente}
\lipsum[4]

\section{A test section with a longer title}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Incredibly fast. What I was looking for. ¡Gracias Gonzalo!

Comment: @damianjb ¡De nada! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option

[image]

which uses the following (I only show the changes to your MWE):

```
% From p.96 - Memoir Manual 
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
  \parbox[t][0pt]{10em}{\upshape\sffamily\raggedright #1}}
%...
\setsechook{\setsecnumformat{\csname the##1\endcsname\par}}
```

---

Another option:

[image]

```
% From p.96 - Memoir Manual 
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
  \parbox[b]{10em}{\upshape\sffamily\raggedright #1}}
%...
\setsechook{\setsecnumformat{\csname the##1\endcsname\par}}
```