# Small indentation appears when adding custom header

Tags: sectioning, memoir, paragraphs

A small indentation appears on the first line of the paragraph when I add \pagestyle{myheader} to the MWE. I don't want it there.
Thanks to Gonzalo Medina's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182674/hanging-section-memoir) I did the part described in Section format.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Begin Section format 
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
  \parbox[t][0pt]{10em}{%
  \upshape\sffamily\raggedright\mbox{}#1}%
}
\newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{%
  \bfseries\smash{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\llap{\marginbox{#1}\kern3em}}}%
}

\setsecindent{0em}
\setsecheadstyle{\marginhead}
\setbeforesecskip{1em}
\setaftersecskip{0em}
\setsechook{%
  \setsecnumformat{\csname   the##1\endcsname\enspace\par\nobreak}%
}
% End Section format

\copypagestyle{myheader}{ruled}
\makeevenhead{myheader}{}{}{My-Name}
\makeoddhead{myheader}{}{}{Other-Name}
\pagestyle{myheader}

\begin{document}

% Layout
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{562pt}{300pt}{*}
\setulmargins{114pt}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{28pt}{24pt}
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{1pt}{1pt}{1pt}
\setlrmargins{210pt}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[4] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this: `\newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{\bfseries\smash{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\llap{\marginbox{#1}\kern3em}}}\kern-1ex}` is a hardwired fix (when the pagestyle is operational)...but why it is that way, I don't know...

Comment: To get [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182674/hanging-section-memoir) result.

Comment: The "custom" part of the header is not the issue.  If you use `\pagestyle{ruled}`, the same behavior results.  Therefore, I suspect the problem is in the definition of the `ruled` header.

Comment: You are right, it is not my custom header, it is the ruled and some other styles that do that.

Comment: The space appears in the passage from boldface sans serif to the normal font, because it's the same as an interword space in boldface Roman; I've not been able to identify the source, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a space that somehow sneaks in the definition of `\sectionmark`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Begin Section format 
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
  \parbox[t][0pt]{10em}{%
  \upshape\sffamily\raggedright\mbox{}#1}%
}
\newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{%
  \bfseries\smash{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\llap{\marginbox{#1}\kern3em}}}%
}

\setsecindent{0em}
\setsecheadstyle{\marginhead}
\setbeforesecskip{1em}
\setaftersecskip{0em}
\setsechook{%
  \setsecnumformat{\csname   the##1\endcsname\enspace\par\nobreak}%
}
% End Section format

\copypagestyle{myheader}{ruled}
\makeevenhead{myheader}{}{}{My-Name}
\makeoddhead{myheader}{}{}{Other-Name}
\pagestyle{myheader}

%%% Fix \sectionmark
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{%
  \@setclcnt{section}{@memmarkcntra}%<------ Missing!
  \advance\c@@memmarkcntra\m@ne
  \markright{%
    \memUChead{%
      \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\c@@memmarkcntra 
        \if@mainmatter
          \@nameuse{sectionmarksn}{\@nameuse{thesection}. \space}%
        \fi
      \fi #1%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Layout (should go before \begin{document})
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{562pt}{300pt}{*}
\setulmargins{114pt}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{28pt}{24pt}
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{1pt}{1pt}{1pt}
\setlrmargins{210pt}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[4] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a bug in `memoir`. Line 1968 (version 2013/05/30 v3.7b) is

```
1968       \@setclcnt{#1}{@memmarkcntra}
```

but should be

```
1968       \@setclcnt{#1}{@memmarkcntra}%
```